# Is there a normal way to "Ping" a COM object?

Tags: windows, com, ipc

I find when implementing IPC or other COM interfaces where the server is in a different apartment, I sometimes want to "ping" the object to see if the other end is still alive.  If I control the interface, I can add a `Ping()` method to it, but I am wondering if there is a more in-box way.

Is there a way without generating application traffic to check if a server is alive?

Consider the scenario where you have a third party authored out of process server that has a long boot time before it can start serving calls.  We trigger the process to start so that when I get a request, I can call the primed service.  The service is buggy, but cannot be edited or fixed, so it sometimes just crashes.  When that happens, I want to restart the service.

My intent is to just keep the application logic idle - I don't want to have to submit synthetic traffic to the server just to verify it is alive.  I also don't want to monitor the process or crashes since multiple instances of this application may be running.  Locating the process hosting the server for my specific COM object may be challenging - and it doesn't mean that it is in a state which can accept calls.  I also cannot use NT Service Recovery Options, since it runs in a user session.

Would `QueryInterface` for a nonexistent `IID` work to generate `RPC_E_DISCONNECTED` and similar or could that be handled by the proxy (hiding server issues)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check COM Interface still alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500503/check-com-interface-still-alive)

Comment: @RaymondChen, it is very similar.  This is not a TOCTOU issue - I'm not pre-checking a subsequent call, I'm trying to get notice when a server dies unexpectedly even if the client is idle.  Perhaps I can edit to be more pointed.

Comment: @RaymondChen, but [How can I tell whether a COM pointer to a remote object is still valid?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111116-00/?p=9103) does seem to exactly answer my question about QI  (Daily reader of The Old New Thing, by the way.  Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge in such a format.)