# Check if Delphi OLE connection still exists

Tags: delphi, ole

When I open an Office application e.g. Word, it appears as an application in the Task Manager. If I kill it from there, calling any specific Word function later causes `EOleSysError` exception. That's normal and works fine. The question is, can Word or any other OLE application existence be checked in a common way without knowing Word it or not?

```
var App, Obj: Variant
begin
  App := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Sleep(100);//placing breakpoint here
// killing Word
// checking if App connection still exists
  IUnknown(App).QueryInterface(IUnknown, Obj);//no exception, doesn't work
  App.Documents.Open('c:\1.docx');//Exception is raised, works but Word specific
end;
```

Comment: This might as well be duplicate of [Check COM Interface still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500503/check-com-interface-still-alive).

Comment: What do you mean by "without knowing Word it or not"?

Comment: @MartynA: he wants this to work for all OLE applications, not just Word

Comment: Yes, true, actually it is duplicate